# SSIS Package with Execute Process Task at first returns: Failed to lock variable

Tags: .net, ssis

My SSIS package starts with Execute Process Task. Process is a net console app (FirstApp) getting data from web service and fills data into the db table. When I run it under OS Windows it's works fine. But when it runs under SSIS package i've an exception:

> SSIS package "STS.dtsx" starting.
>   Error: 0xC0014054 at EPT grab data from WS STS: Failed to lock variable "
>   " for read access with error 0xC0010001 "The variable cannot be found. This occurs when an attempt is made to retrieve a variable from the Variables collection on a container during execution of the package, and the variable is not there. The variable name may have changed or the variable is not being created.".
>   Error: 0xC002F304 at EPT grab data from WS STS, Execute Process Task: An error occurred with the following error message: "Failed to lock variable "
>   " for read access with error 0xC0010001 "The variable cannot be found. This occurs when an attempt is made to retrieve a variable from the Variables collection on a container during execution of the package, and the variable is not there. The variable name may have changed or the variable is not being created.".
>   ".
>   Task failed: EPT grab data from WS STS
>   SSIS package "STS.dtsx" finished: Success.

I've another Execute Process Task at the end of task queue of SSIS package with .net console app (SecondApp) sending data through web service.It works fine.

FirsApp and SecondApp do not take arguments and returns nothing.

I set "everyone" access to the folder with FirstApp, disable firewall etc.
I've added another "stub" task before FirstApp.
I've changed failed task with FirstApp to SecondApp. 
I've set similar settings for FirstApp and SeconApp tasks.
Nothing helps to me.
Any idea ?
Thanks.

Comment: It might not take arguments, but in SSIS you must have specified some empty parameter, which is not found amongst package params.

Comment: SecondApp do not take arguments too. But it works fine in the end of queue of SSIS package. I've changed first (FirstApp) task params with empty and non-empty arguments. Still won't work.

Comment: Using .bat file in same task to run FirstApp haven't helped me too.

Comment: This could appear for various reasons most frequent are: a) scope or namespace of the variable is not correctly defined b) property IsSourcePathVariable is wrongly used c) an expression modifies the value of the variable before execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is recreate task. It works for me.
Please, be attentive! When you launch app using Execute Process Task (with empty WorkingDir property) working dir for app sets same SSIS packet dir.